# How to display integer value in angular front-end?

Tags: angular, typescript

After entering and submitting integer input value from Angular front-end, it converts into decimal. Is there a way to display the value in integer in the front end?

**codes are given below**

**component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
let postData = [];
for (var k in this.measures) {
  if (!this.measures.hasOwnProperty(k)) { continue }
  let secs = this.measures[k]
  for (var i in secs) {
    var item1 = secs["items"]
    for (var j in item1) {
      var item2 = item1[j]
      for (var l in item2) {
        var listItem = item2["items"]
        for (var li in listItem) {
          this.model = new MeasurementChange(listItem[li].id, 
          listItem[li].percent_complete);
          postData.push(this.model);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Enter Input</mat-label>
   <input type = number [(ngModel)]="row.percent_complete" 
     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="percent_complete" 
      name="percent_complete" matInput placeholder="Enter Progress (%)">
 </mat-form-field>
```

**service.ts**

```
  postEntries(formData: Array<MeasurementChange>): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + this.postDataUrl, formData);
   }
```

Comment: You may use `DecimalPipe` pipe of Angular itself. You can find this article helpful: [https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but should this 'var item1 = secs["items"]' be 'var item1 = secs[i]' and this 'var listItem = item2["items"]' to be 'var listItem = item2[l]' ? Just a tought, maybe use forEach it will really help the readability and prevent errors with indexes